# Is there a cleaner way to sum all numerical properties in a class individually?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class, represented below as Example class. In my DoSomeLogic Method, I need to sum a collection of Example class, and want to return a new instance of Example class where each numerical property contains the sum of that property from the collection.

Below is an example of how i would typically do this, but my problem is that I am continuously updating my example class, adding new properties etc. When doing this I need to remember to also update the sum method for example class too, or my code is broken, which seems like a hurdle/vulnerability I'd like to avoid.

Can anyone show me a better way to do this generically, so i don't need to update the sum method if i add a new numerical property to the example class?

```
public class Example 
{
    public Example()
    {
    }

    public Example(int a, int b, float c)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
        IgnoreThis = "Non numerical properties should be ignored by the sum method";
    }

    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public float C { get; set; }
    public string IgnoreThis {get; set;}
}
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class Extension
{
    public static Example Sum(this IEnumerable<Example> source)
    {
        Example result = new Example();
        result.A = source.Sum(x => x.A);
        result.B = source.Sum(x => x.B);
        result.C = source.Sum(x => x.C);
        return result;
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Usage
{
    private List<Example> Examples = new List<Example>();

    public void DoSomeLogic()
    {
        Examples.Add(new Example(1, 2, 3.75f));
        Examples.Add(new Example(2, 3, 6.25f));
        Example SumOfEachIndividualProperty = Examples.Sum();
        //Expected result from logging SumOfEachIndividualProperty.A is 3;
        //Expected result from logging SumOfEachIndividualProperty.B is 5;
        //Expected result from logging SumOfEachIndividualProperty.C is 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what you are saying is that you might be adding numeric properties D, E, F etc to the "Example" class?

Comment: Define "numeric". Do you just need to deal with `int` and `float` or are more exotic types possibly in the mix?

Comment: Smells like a design problem having the need to constantly add numerical properties to it. If they have equal meanings it might be more convenient to use a list for that or at least back the properties in a List so you can easily iterate over the List or Dictionary without the need to use reflection or something like that.

Comment: @Ralf Yes, there is a lot of context missing from the question. Does seem a little like an X-Y problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could solve this using reflection, but I think that's overkill (and would not be very performant).

You could consider putting the "add" functionality into the class itself:

```
public class Example
{
    public Example()
    {
    }

    public Example(int a, int b, float c)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
        IgnoreThis = "Non numerical properties should be ignored by the sum method";
    }

    public void Add(Example other)
    {
        A += other.A;
        B += other.B;
        C += other.C;
    }

    public int    A          { get; set; }
    public int    B          { get; set; }
    public float  C          { get; set; }
    public string IgnoreThis { get; set; }
}
```

Then your extension method would become:

```
public static Example Sum(this IEnumerable<Example> source)
{
    var result = new Example();

    foreach (var example in source)
    {
        result.Add(example);
    }

    return result;
}
```

When you add new members to the `Example` class you would need to update the `Add()` method accordingly, but you would not need to modify the extension method.

---

ADDENDUM: Since someone was wondering about using `INumber` in the implementation that uses reflection, I thought I'd have a go.

Firstly, here's a example class that you want to sum the properties for:

```
public class Example
{
    public Example()
    {
    }

    public Example(int a, int b, float c)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
        IgnoreThis = "Non numerical properties should be ignored by the sum method";
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"A={A}, B={B}, C={C}";
    }

    public int    A { get; set; }
    public int    B { get; set; }
    public float  C { get; set; }
    public string IgnoreThis { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Here's a sample program that demonstrates how we want to add up the properties for all the items in a collection. Note the expected output:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var items = new[]
        {
            new Example(1, 4, 7),
            new Example(2, 5, 8),
            new Example(3, 6, 9)
        };

        var totals = Extension.SumNumericProperties(items);

        Console.WriteLine(totals); // A=6, B=15, C=24
    }
}
```

And here's how I implemented the `Extension` class:

If you need to add additional numeric types (e.g. `decimal`) you'd just need to add an new `numericProperties` item with the required type and add calls to `sumValueTo()` and `assignResults()`.

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static T SumNumericProperties<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) where T: new()
    {
        var intAdders    = numericProperties<int,    T>();
        var floatAdders  = numericProperties<float,  T>();
        var shortAdders  = numericProperties<short,  T>();
        var doubleAdders = numericProperties<double, T>();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            sumValueTo(intAdders,    item);
            sumValueTo(floatAdders,  item);
            sumValueTo(shortAdders,  item);
            sumValueTo(doubleAdders, item);
        }

        T result = new();

        assignResults(intAdders,    result);
        assignResults(floatAdders,  result);
        assignResults(shortAdders,  result);
        assignResults(doubleAdders, result);

        return result;
    }

    static void sumValueTo<TNumber, T>(List<NumericPropertyAdder<TNumber>> numericProperties, T item) where TNumber : INumber<TNumber>
    {
        foreach (var numericProperty in numericProperties)
        {
            numericProperty.Add(item!);
        }
    }

    static void assignResults<TNumber, T>(List<NumericPropertyAdder<TNumber>> numericProperties, T item) where TNumber : INumber<TNumber>
    {
        foreach (var numericProperty in numericProperties)
        {
            numericProperty.AssignResult(item!);
        }
    }

    static List<NumericPropertyAdder<TNumber>> numericProperties<TNumber, TOwner>() where TNumber : INumber<TNumber>
    {
        return (
            from   prop in typeof(TOwner).GetProperties()
            where  prop.PropertyType.IsAssignableTo(typeof(INumber<TNumber>))
            select new NumericPropertyAdder<TNumber>(prop)
        ).ToList();
    }
}

public sealed class NumericPropertyAdder<T> where T: INumber<T>             
{
    public NumericPropertyAdder(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        _property = property;
    }

    public void Add(object propertyHolder)
    {
        var value = (T) _property.GetValue(propertyHolder)!;
        _sum += value;
    }

    public T Sum()
    {
        return _sum;
    }

    public void AssignResult(object propertyHolder)
    {
        _property.SetValue(propertyHolder, _sum);
    }

    T _sum = T.AdditiveIdentity;

    readonly PropertyInfo _property;
}
```

My conclusion is that the added complexity of handling the generic types like this might not actually be worth it... ;)

Comment: Wow great solution, thanks! And I also think that it can be even better with generic math.

Comment: Yes and no ;) He had the problem that he might forget to update the "sum" code when adding a property. Here he must still update the Add method so the problem has been moved not actually solved.

Comment: @Ralf But moved to where it belongs. And avoids any issues to do with adding a numerical property which should *not* be part of the calculation (which would be picked up by reflection). I agree with your comment to the OP suggesting a List for the items that should be added up.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the fantastic answers provided by Vladim Martynov and Matthew Watson I decided to move the add function to the example class as suggested by MW.

I also decided to use reflection to validate the add function once on application startup (in my developer context only), to avoid the performance hit of using reflection in production code.

so my final code looks something like the below

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
public class Example 
{
    public Example()
    {
    }

    public Example(int a, int b, float c)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
    }

    public static bool ValidateAddMethod()
    {
        var intProperties = typeof(Example)
      .GetProperties()
      .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(int));
        var floatProperties = typeof(Example)
        .GetProperties()
      .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(float));
        Example example1 = new Example();

        foreach(PropertyInfo intInfo in intProperties)
        {
            intInfo.SetValue(example1, 1);
        }

        foreach(PropertyInfo floatInfo in floatProperties)
        {
            floatInfo.SetValue(example1, 1f);
        }

        Example example0 = new Example();

        example0.Add(example1);

        foreach (PropertyInfo intInfo in intProperties)
        {
            int currentInt = (int)intInfo.GetValue(example0);
            if (currentInt != 1)
                throw new System.Exception($"The property {intInfo.Name} has not been added to the sum method of the Example class.");
        }

        foreach (PropertyInfo floatInfo in floatProperties)
        {
            float currentFloat = (float)floatInfo.GetValue(example0);
            if (currentFloat != 1f)
                throw new System.Exception($"The property {floatInfo.Name} has not been added to the sum method of the Example class.");
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void Add(Example other)
    {
        this.A += other.A;
        this.B += other.B;
        this.C += other.C;
    }

    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public float C { get; set; }
    public float NotAdded { get; set; }
}
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class Extension
{
    public static Example Sum(this IEnumerable<Example> source)
    {
        Example result = new Example();
        foreach(Example example in source)
        {
            result.Add(example);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Usage
{
    //Not my actual implementation but should serve to illustrate the idea.
    bool IsDeveloperMode = true;

    public Usage()
    {
        if(IsDeveloperMode)
        {
            Example.ValidateAddMethod();
        }

    }

    private List<Example> Examples = new List<Example>();

    public void DoSomeLogic()
    {
        Examples.Add(new Example(1, 2, 3.75f));
        Examples.Add(new Example(2, 3, 6.25f));
        Example SumEachIndividualProperty = Examples.Sum();
    }
}
```

Comment: Another thing you could consider: If you're using unit tests as part of continuous integration, you could move the validation code over to a unit test class.

Comment: Thanks this is a good suggestion, and probably where this type of code belongs. The project is not using unit tests though, so I'll make do with the above workaround for now.